# How to change default url in a react app?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How to change default url in a react app? So that the application does not open with http://localhost:3000/paper-dashboard-react, but ***localhost:3000***?

routes.js:

```
import Dashboard from "views/Dashboard.js";
import Users from "views/Users.js";


var routes = [
{
path: "/dashboard",
name: "Dashboard",
icon: "nc-icon nc-bank",
component: Dashboard,
layout: "/admin",
},
{
path: "/users",
name: "Users",
icon: "nc-icon nc-single-02",
component: Users,
layout: "/admin",
},

];
export default routes;
```

Login.js:

```
export default function BasicExample() {
 return (
  <Router>
    <Switch>

      <Route path="/admin" render={(props) => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
       <Route exact path="/paper-dashboard-react" component={Login}>
          <Login />
       </Route>
     </Switch>
   </Router> 
 )
}
```

Its a theme I downloaded from https://www.creative-tim.com/product/paper-dashboard-react.

Comment: Kindly provide more description about your issue. share with us your routes file. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it like this:

```
<Route exact path="/paper-dashboard-react" component={Login}>
      <Login />
</Route>
<Route exact path="/" component={Login}>
      <Login />
</Route>


useEffect(() => {
   history_redirect.push("/");
})
```

Comment: I think this solution is not the best, probably the theme that you downloaded has a setting that says to open `/paper-dashboard-react`, you need to find this setting and remove it.